# Not able to run Javascript in android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, webview

I am making a automatic facebook join group app. For this I am making a webview and load the specific facebook group url to this webview. Now what I want is press the 'Join Group' button automatically for this I made a script and run it in webview:

```
  private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
       view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementsByClassName('bu bv bw').submit();})()");
    }
```

The problem is nothing happens when this script runs, I have gone through many posts regarding this but not able to get it please help!!!
I am also posting the code of how I setup the webview:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            name.setText(
                    "User ID: "
                            + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                            + "\n" +
                            "Auth Token: "
                            + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
            );


            WebView ourBrow;
            ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            // cancel the web intent that default in android setting
            ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
            String url = "https://m.facebook.com/groups/819387484767105";

            // webView settings
            ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            ourBrow.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            ourBrow.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
            ourBrow.loadUrl(url);
        }
```

Comment: There is no API for joining groups. Be aware that Facebook doesn't allow what you are doing

Comment: yes, WizKid i knew there is no api for joining groups ,but i have seen plugins which are able to do automatic 'join button' press using javascript insertion, i am trying to do same using android webview. Can u please help me with that.

Comment: There is no API because Facebook don't want the feature. Feel free to tell me about the other apps that are doing it and I'll report them

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether you really got the 'bu bv bw' element in the runtime, second, `document.getElementsByClassName` will return an array, so you can also try document.getElementsByClassName('bu bv bw')[0].submit()

Comment: Hello Day Wong , Can u please tell me how can I check whether 'bu bv bw' returned something or not at runtime.

Comment: console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('bu bv bw').length) should DO, and if `https://m.facebook.com/groups/819387484767105` is the webpage you want to go, you can test it on chrome browser console. I tested `https://m.facebook.com/groups/819387484767105` with `document.getElementsByClassName('bu bv bw')` it return 0 object @ShivamGarg

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please provide me the id of 'join group' button to use in place of 'bu bv bw'.

Comment: @ShivamGarg seems class is generated and will change over time  `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()`